# Excel VBA arabic characters are displayed wrong

Tags: excel, vba

Arabic characters in excel are displaying just fine. Also in vba code, characters are also displayed correctly.
But when I run the macro, the output of the code that should be in arabic letters is shown with foreign characters that don't make any sense.
[Arabic characters are not arabic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdtsd.png)

In the "Language for non-Unicode programs", I've changed system locale to arabic and English (United Arab Emirates) but nothing changed.
I also in the vba editor format I changed the font to Courier New (Arabic) and still nothing changed.
[system locale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQaqJ.png)
[editor format font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQKvz.png)

EDIT: When I tried changing the system locale to Arabic(Lebanon) on another laptop it worked fine. But on my Fujitsu Lifebook U758 (Imported from Germany) when I tried the same thing, it didn't work.

Comment: You should only use ASCII characters in the VBA editor as it lacks Unicode support. All characters outside the ASCII range in the editor get converted depending on the system locale and you get code that runs unpredictably. Note that only the editor doesn't support Unicode, VBA does support it and it uses UTF-16 encoding internally, just like Excel. One solution to get such Unicode strings in VBA is to store your strings in Excel cells (maybe on a hidden worksheet) and read these cells with your macro. Then you can use and manipulate those strings with VBA as you desire.